# Inserting data from csv file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I am trying to upload a csv file after then the file data will be print/insert.But my code is not printing the data according to my code.It is printing Id: Marks complete 1.But my file is uploading.
my input csv file format is

```
     Id,Marks
     20,46
     20,46
     32,45
```

My controller code is

```
     public function upload_marks(){
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
        $config['max_size'] = '10000';

       $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('marksfile'))
        {
          echo  $this->upload->display_errors();               
        }
      else
       {
        $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
        $fileName = $uploadData['file_name'];
        $this->load->library('csvreader');
        $csvData = $this->csvreader->parse_file('./uploads/',$fileName);
        foreach($csvData as $data){
            echo " ID: ".$data['id'];
            echo " Marks: ".$data['marks'];
        }
        echo " Complete 1";  
    }
}
```

**Where is the problem ? Could you get my error ?**

Comment: do `print_r($csvData[]);` before foreach

Comment: I think it is `$csvData` not `$csvData[]`

Comment: @kumar_v,
editor displaying error, can not use[] for reading this line.

Comment: update your question with latest code

Comment: change `$csvData['vv']` to `$csvData`

Comment: @kumar_v, 
Now the code is updated. changed $csvData['vv'] to $csvData.
But.
 now output is Array ( [0] => ) ID: Marks: Complete 1

Comment: change `print_r($csvData);` to `var_dump($csvData)` to check whether you are getting data or not.

Comment: @kumar_v.
After changing it output is
array(1) { [0]=> bool(false) } ID: Marks: Complete 1

Comment: so  you are not getting data from library. check your library

Comment: @kumar_v, 
after changing print_r($csvData); to var_dump($csvData).
Output is:
bool(false)
 Invalid argument supplied for foreach() 
Undefined variable: data

Comment: check your library. Because it returns the false instead of data. there may error in file path or empty file.

Comment: In `('./uploads/',$fileName)` I believe that comma should be a period.

Comment: @Samutz, 
I am not clear of your message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your data is in B1,B2,B3,B4 position for your excell sheet, Then code as given below with phpexcel library.

```
                  $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
          $fileName = $uploadData['file_name'];
          $this->load->library('excel');
          $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
          $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('./uploads/'.$fileName);
          $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);

          $prof = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B1')->getValue();
          $term = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B2')->getValue();
          $sbjCode = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B3')->getValue();
          $year = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B4')->getValue();
```

After then code as above for your rest data according to position. Hope this will works .

Answer (score 0):

Use PHPExcel Library it works fantastic, I have used same in various projects.

https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: After wasting my three day trying to CSV, now trying to phpexcel

Comment: This is a input file format. How could I get these values using phpexcel, Could you help me ?


Prof: 1
Term: 1
Subject Code: 1
CP: wrtnMarks
Year : 2014

        I d Marks

        1 34
        41 44
        42 44

I will insert id and marks in a table depending on top data as condition.